# Tastypie: can't get one field from related resource

Tags: django, django-queryset, tastypie

Problem in that ToManyField returns set of objects or set of urls. How i can get only one field from related table?

```
class PlaceResource(ModelResource):
    location    = fields.ManyToManyField(PlaceLocationResource, 'location')
    action = fields.ToManyField('menus.resources.ActionResource',
                            attribute= lambda bundle: bundle.obj.action.distinct('type').only('name'),
                                null=True, related_name='place', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = PlaceInfo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'place'

        filtering = {
            'id' : ALL,
        }

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        #raise sdf
        bundle.data['type'] = bundle.obj.type.name
        bundle.data['name'] = bundle.obj.name.name
        bundle.data['close_time'] = bundle.obj.close_time
        bundle.data['location'] = {}
        bundle.data['location']['address'] = (bundle.obj.location.all()[0]).address
        bundle.data['location']['latitude'] = (bundle.obj.location.all()[0]).latitude
        bundle.data['location']['longtitude'] = (bundle.obj.location.all()[0]).longtitude

        if bundle.obj.comments == None:
            bundle.data['comments'] = 0
        if bundle.obj.price == None:
            bundle.data['price'] = 0
        #if bundle.obj.rate_amount == None:
        #    bundle.data['rate_amount'] = 0
        #if bundle.obj.rate_makr == None:
        #    bundle.data['rate_makr'] = 0
        bundle.data['rate_amount'] = {
            1 : 10,
            2 : 15,
            3 : 40,
            4 : 35,
            5 : 27
        }
        if bundle.obj.open_time == None:
            bundle.data['open_time'] = 'Unsetted'
        if bundle.obj.close_time == None:
            bundle.data['close_time'] = 'Unsetted'
        if bundle.obj.location == None:
            bundle.data['location'] = 'Unsetted'
        if bundle.obj.type == 'restaurant.PlaceType.None':
            bundle.data['type'] = 'Unsetted'

        #bundle.obj.action  = bundle.obj.action.distinct('type').only('type')
        #bundle.data['types'] = bundle.obj.action

        return bundle
```

I tried to manipulate with querySet of 'action' and add method 'only', but it doesn't work ('distinct' workes fine), it returns all fields of the 'action'. Maybe there is same method 'only' exactly for tastypie, but i didn't saw that. Thank you.

**UPDATED:**

```
bundle.data['types']  = []
for i in bundle.obj.action.distinct('type'):
    bundle.data['types'].append(i.type)
```

I solved it in such way, but i want get normal QuerySet without iterations

Answer (score 0):

You should create one property and add that property name into fields list.

Comment: Sorry, it was a part of the code, i've updateded my question